# Nocaptcha recaptcha always falls back to old style recaptcha

Tags: recaptcha

I am implementing the new no captcha recaptcha and was successfully testing it this morning. However, as of an hour ago, it started to always give me old style text after I check the check box? Are there some kind of limits/configuration issues I am rubbing against?

Firefox 34.0.5/Chrome 39.0.2171.95 on MacOsx Yosemite.

Comment: I've been getting this too.